# Delete user from db and folder dedicated

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner with php and have created a code displaying a table with the data concerning my users, that is in my database. 
This is the code I used.
    
    
    **Name**
    **Surname**
    **Date of Birth**
    **Town of Birth**
    **Code**
    **Address**
    **E-mail**
    ";

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['Surname'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['DateofBirth'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['TownofBirth'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['Code'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
echo'<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$row['Code'].'">Delete</a></td>';
echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

I also have created a delete.php file which allows to delete users from the db by clicking on the "delete" link, but I also wanted this code to remove a folder named with the username of the user, that is situated in the current work directory. This is the code I wrote:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypassword");
mysql_select_db("mydb",$con);
function deletedir($dirname){
    if(file_exists($dirname) && is_file($dirname)) {
        unlink($dirname);
    } elseif(is_dir($dirname)) {
        $handle=opendir($dirname);
        while(false!==($file=readdir($handle))){
            if(is_file($dirname.$file)){
                unlink($dirname.$file);
            }
        }
        $handle=closedir($handle);
        rmdir($dirname);
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Code='$id'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $username=$row['Username'];
        deletedir($username);
    }

    $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM Users WHERE Code='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    header("location: index.php");
} else {
    header("location: index.php");
}

?>
```

This code deletes the user from the db but it doesn't remove the folder called $username. Please help me to understand where the error is. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors in the error log?

Comment: No my code doesn't return any error and there are no errors in the error log.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).
 **Also as a side effect of that, your code can allow arbitrary files on server to be deleted.**

Comment: Ok I'll try that way, but can you find any mistakes in this code?

Comment: Your code is full of XSS and SQL injection vulnerabilities. If users can pick their own username, then they might be able to overwrite files, too.

Comment: I understand this but I won't put it online, so it's not that important for me at the moment. However you are right.

Comment: If you add `error_reporting( E_ALL );` to the top of your script, do you get any additional output on the screen? How are the directories created? Without knowing how the directories are created, my first hunch is that you have a permissions problem.

Comment: I've checked and it doesn't return any particular output by adding that command. I've also checked the permissions on the folders and they are all 0777, so I really can't understand...

Comment: For Chris Ostmo: the directories are created authomatically when a user logs in for the first time, but this would be a webpage for the administrator.

Comment: Are the directories empty after the script runs? If so, were they empty before the script runs? I think that the places you have `$dirname.$file` should be `$dirname.'/'.$file` Try echoing all of the `$dirname` and `$dirname.$file` variables just before you use them and see if any fail to match what is expected. Maybe post the results to this thread.

Comment: Another question... You are just passing a username as the `$dirname` argument. Is the username a full file path or relative to where the script resides? If you're not sure try `echo getcwd();` at the top of your `deletedir` function.

Comment: $dirname is a relative file path, since the directory $dirname is in the same work directory as the php script.

Comment: About your previous question: the directories are empty but I'm now doing some attempts with non-empty directories. I'll post the results...

Comment: Echo the values of each of the variables you declare inside of each path through the code (each `if` `elseif` `while` etc.) to make sure that you are getting into the paths of code you are expecting and that the values represent what you expect. I would also follow the instructions given in my provided answer to use a full path instead of relying on a relative path. That way, there are no guesses about exactly what PHP thinks you are asking it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

`unlink` and `rmdir` need a full path to the files/directories to remove if the deleting script isn't in the same directory as what you are trying to delete.

Try adding something like this to the top of your deletedir function:

```
$dir = "/opt/www/userdirs"
$dirname = $dir . '/' . $dirname;
```

Change "/opt/www/userdirs" to the directory where your directories to delete reside.

And I think that you also need to change all of these:

```
$dirname.$file
```

To:

```
$dirname . '/' . $file
```

Comment: It seems that my pc is a bit down at the moment, but I think you've pointed me into the right direction. I'll let you know within some time.

Comment: Ok Chris! Everything works brilliantly now and I'm truly excited! Many many thanks for being so helpful :)